# Incorrect number of dimensions: extracting elements from multiple rdata files

Tags: r, for-loop, data-extraction, storing-data, rdata

**PROBLEM**
I have many `.RData` files in one folder and I want to extract the coordinates continued in each `.rdata` file. I'd also like to link the concomitant file `name(use_hab)` and `datetime(dt)` to each row of their respective coordinates.

**CODE**

```
file.namez<-list.files("C:/fitting/fitdata/7 27 2015") #name of files
#file.namez.rev<-file.namez[grep(".RData",file.namez)]

datastor<-data.frame(matrix(NA,length(file.namez),4))
names(datastor)<-c("use_hab",paste("B",1:3,sep=""))

allresults<-NULL

for(i in 1:length(file.namez))
  {
  datastor<-NULL
  print(file.namez[i])
  load(paste("C:/fitting/fitdata/7 27 2015/",file.namez[i], sep=""))
  use_hab <- as.character(as.data.frame(strsplit(file.namez[i],"_an"))[2,])# this line is used to remove unwanted parts of the file name
  use_hab <- gsub(".RData","", use_hab)
  datastor <- fitdata$coords
  datastor$use_hab <- use_hab
  datastor$dt <- fitdata$dt
  allresults <- rbind(allresults, datastor[,c(3,4,1,2)])
}
```

This is only result before the error message:

```
[1] "fitdata_anw514_yr2008.RData"
```

**ERROR**

> Error in datastor[, c(3, 4, 1, 2)] : incorrect number of dimensions
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In datastor$use_hab <- use_hab : Coercing LHS to a list

**QUESTION**
How am I getting the incorrect number of dimensions? Each file name should have 1098 coordinates and date time. In total, 63 files x 1098 rows with 4 columns(filename, datetime, x, y).

The desired result is to have the file name as the first column, the date time as the second column, and the x and y coordinates as the third and fourth columns.

Comment: Load each file, typing `ls()` each time to see what the new objects are. Run `str()` and/or `dim()` to confirm dimensions. If there are many, just automate that (`store.dim <- list();` ..... ; `store.dim[[i]] <- dim(object[i])`)

Comment: @rbatt could you elaborate the automate process you mention?

Comment: @rbatt could you elaborate on the automate process you mention? Did you mean store the dimensions of what is in the rdata files or what the loop is supposed to produce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
  datastor <- fitdata$coords
```

with

```
 datastor$coords <- fitdata$coords
```

The error message `Coercing LHS to a list` is thrown when you try to access something with `$` that does not support this. `datastor <- fitdata$coords` changes `datastor` to the data type of `fitdata$coords`.

Also, you'd change

```
allresults<-NULL
datastor<-NULL
```

to

```
allresults <- data.frame()
datastor <- data.frame()
```

but this may just my personal preference.